# OpenVPN Domain Suffix

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I've got an OpenVPN server to access our infrastructure remotely. All internal infrastructure is assigned a DNS name in the form `SERVER_NAME.my.company.domain`. When on site the the DHCP suffix is set to "my.company.domain" through DHCP option 15. I've tried to do the same through OpenVPN but it doesn't seem to work.

My server configuration has the following:

```
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN my.company.domain"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.4.0.21"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.4.0.22"
```

When connecting through OpenVPN Connect on both Mac and Windows the search domain is listed correctly in the log file. DNS servers are pushed correctly as I can access infrastructure through their full DNS name, however when I use only `SERVER_NAME` without the suffix I'm unable to access anything.

Answer (score 5):

I ran across this problem today. This condition is discussed here for further reference: [Open VPN Community Wiki and Tracker](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/1209?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=pmd_AgCBbVTENjAVHP0VYWvrVwVXwC7U52yoh9MH4zXLTSM-1634305685-0-gqNtZGzNAhCjcnBszQo9)

Modify:

server.conf

```
push "dhcp-option ADAPTER_DOMAIN_SUFFIX <SEARCH_DOMAIN>"
```

or

client.conf

```
dhcp-option ADAPTER_DOMAIN_SUFFIX <SEARCH_DOMAIN>
```

Comment: for OpenVPN 2.x use `DOMAIN-SEARCH`. Probably it will be supportedd in 3.x at some point too.

Answer (score 0):

The correct dhcp option in your case would be DOMAIN-SEARCH (119) instead of DOMAIN (15) because option 15 is the domain that the client should add to its own hostname while option 119 is the DNS domain search list. See IANA's [Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) and Bootstrap Protocol (BOOTP) Parameters](https://www.iana.org/assignments/bootp-dhcp-parameters/bootp-dhcp-parameters.xhtml#options) list for details.

It looks like OpenVPN does not support dhcp option 119 according to [ticket #1209](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/1209)

Comment: I was able to get option 15 working in all clients I've tested but OpenVPN Connect so I think it's a client limitation/bug.

Comment: The names of `dhcp-option` do not map to the options defined in the DHCP option list, but rather to the internal OpenVPN names. The OpenVPN docs says to use `DOMAIN` for the connection specific DNS suffix

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a limitation with the OpenVPN Connect client on both Windows and macOS. I have tried importing the same configuration using the following clients with success:

- OpenVPN GUI
- tunXten
- Viscosity
- Tunnelblick